# Trying to get access token for Sharepoint rest api call through javascript in a sharepoint add in, facing an issue of CORS policy error

Tags: javascript, cors, postman, sharepoint-online

We are trying to create a Sharepoint Add in. There I need to generate access token for making some Sharepoint rest api call. I am able to generate that from postman but while doing it from Javascript code in Sharepoint Add in it is showing me an CORS Policy error. The error is given below:

> Access to fetch at 'https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/{TenantID}/tokens/oAuth/2' from origin 'https://DomainName-d9cbe540d4fdef.sharepoint.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

```
const tokenRequest = {
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
    client_id: "clientID@TenantID",
    client_secret: "Secret Value",
    resource: "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/domain@tenantID",
};

const endpoint = 'https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/{TenantID}/tokens/oAuth/2';
// Make token request and handle response
fetch(endpoint, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        crossorigin: true,
        mode: 'no-cors'
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams(tokenRequest),
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data.access_token))
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Generate Token in javascript for calling sharepoint rest api.

Comment: These endpoints are deliberately not CORS-enabled - because you are not supposed to use them from the client side in the first place. This API call needs your client secret, and that must not be exposed in client-side code! You _need to_ make this call from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Making "app authentication" (which means using credentials with their own rights, and not using the connected user context) is a big no no as it is a security open door, since you have to store credentials openly in your front end development.

In such case, you must have a back-end to make the requests: Azure Function, Web App, Server on a raspberry PI, Logic Apps, Power Automate, ... whatever you decide, but the back-end must make the "application" calls.

What is expected in a browser environment is actually a three legged authentication in the Microsoft universe, meaning you want to use your connected user to make queries in his name. To do so, you must be using OAuth, and and AAD Application to be allowed to use the user context.